# How do I create a choice column with integer values?

Tags: column, choice-field

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx) *"You cannot create integer base-type choice fields"*.

Is there a workaround for this?

If I wanted a integer field with a set of possible values I could use a Number column and a validation formula, but this would not be user friendly since you only get to know the possible values after validation has failed.

A Dropdown or a set of Radio buttons would be more intuitive.

Comment: The most common work around is to add the numbers as strings, and then, if needed, cast the strings to integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isn't a multivalue choice field you could possibly add a calculated column to show the value as number.

1. Set up your choice column with the proper values as numbers.
2. Set up a calculated column with formula =VALUE([ChoiceColumn]).

Regarding the problem that the user isn't aware what values are possible you can use the description field within the column settings.
This description will be shown (in standard SharePoint Edit Forms) at the field itself.
Of couse the user needs to read this description, but we all know how users like to read. (EULA? Meh, scroll down, click yes, give away my soul, who cares? ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you create a non-integer based dropdown or radio button but if you need to use the value as an integer maybe create a calculated field with number data type and get the value of your dropdown list.

Comment: Say I have a radio button Column1 and a calculated Number Column2 with the formula `=[Column1]`. How and where is the value of Column1 converted to an Integer?

Comment: first you must make the return of your field as number the next trick is to put something like =[Column1] + 0 that would do the trick :)